# Moving TDWC from Linux to Windows server

Tags: mainframe, zos, workload-scheduler

We currently have TDWC (8.5.1) stood up on a Linux server.
 (A very OLD Linux server that doesn't have much horsepower). 
It's working fine, but slow. We need to upgrade it, and 9.2 
is as high as we can go due to our Service Provider limitations. 
Instead of upgrading it in place, I would like to install it on a 
brand new Windows 2012-R2 server that was provisioned just for Workload Automation tools. I've scoured the manuals and the forums and I don't see anything that addresses this specifically. I assume this install would be handled as a brand new install and not an upgrade as far as the server goes.

My question/concern is about the Started Task and Parmlib on the Mainframe. As long as I am using the same host & port on the mainframe, and the z/OS Connector, wouldn't it be as simple as shutting down the old TDWC and starting up the new 9.2 DWC release? Wouldn't it connect to the same Started Task as the current release does?

The `SERPTDWC` member on the mainframe 
contains the following...

```
 /* TCPIP ZCONNECTOR SERVER                                 

 SERVOPTS SUBSYS(TWSC)                                      
  PROTOCOL(TCP)                                             
  USERMAP(USERS)                                            
 TCPOPTS TCPIPJOBNAME(NETITCP)                              
  HOSTNAME(DPSMVS1.EDS.EXPRESS-SCRIPTS.COM)                 
  SRVPORTNUMBER(31121)                                      
 INIT CALENDAR(DEFAULT)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in running multiple connectors connect to the same server started task, this is the standard configuration when running a DWC cluster.

This does not require any change to `SERVOPTS` or `TCPOPTS`, the only check to do is to verify that the users authenticating on the new connector are correctly mapped in the `USERMAP`, the new connector will present the users with new connector name and you may need to add them in the `USERS` parameter member